# What is meant by "KDF2" vs "PBKDF2"?

Tags: key-derivation, pbkdf-2

I see many references to KDF2 here, but all links are broken and Wikipedia does not have an entry for KDF2.  Is KDF2 a specific standard for Key Derivation *without a password*?

Ultimately, I am trying to make sense of why [KDF2 is listed as PRNG for Crypto++ on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto%2B%2B#Algorithms).

Comment: KDF2 is a specific standard for key-based key derivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KDF2 is a KDF defined in ISO 18033.  You can find a draft of that spec [here](http://www.shoup.net/iso/std4.pdf).  See section 6.2.3.

As to why it's listed as a PRNG, remember that a KDF relies on a pseudo random function (PRF), so it's output needs to be random.

Comment: It can be considered a PRNG in the same sense that AES-CTR is one.

Comment: I don't think any PRF should be called a PRNG. For a PRNG I would at least expect an option to re-seed, even if that re-seeding operation would take a statically sized input. I would also expect it to return numbers rather than bits; DRBG would otherwise be a more apt name. It's unfortunate that these kinds of concepts get mixed up all the time. But yeah, KDF's and CTR mode are sometimes called PRNG's :(